# Wrapper Classes vs Classes(user-defined)

Tags: java, tostring

```
class person {
   int id;
}
class sample {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Integer i = new Integer(1234);
        Person p = new Person();
        List l = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(l);
        }
}
```

Output:

1234
person@659e0bfd
[ ]

In general when we try to println the object reference,it prints " getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())" , but when it comes to wrapper classes and collections , it prints a completely different output.Why is it?

Answer (score 2):

When you do  `System.out.println(obj)` , it prints the result of `obj.toString()` method, if your custom class does not override `toString()` , it uses the `toString()` method from parent class which has `toString()` method overriden (In your case, that parent class is `Object` , as that is the default parent class for all classes unless another class is explicitly specified as the parent using `extends` keyword)  , which is what returns the following as per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) -

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

In case of Wrapper classes , they have overriden the `toString()` method to give the correct result.

---

Consider an Example -

```
class p {
   String id;
   public p(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String toString() {
       return "ID :" + id;
   }
}
class a {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       p p1 = new p("1001");
       System.out.println(p1);
   }
}
```

When we run this, it would print -

```
ID :1001
```